# How to get yesterday date in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-run-time-library

I know you can get the current time using the `Now()` function, but how would you get the date of yesterday?

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/resources/white-papers

Comment: @DelphiCoder the link no longer works.

Comment: @dummzeuch still working here!

Comment: Apparently a temporary issue. Now it works.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use `Date - 1` ?

Since one day is 1.0 in `TDateTime` encoding, substracting `1` is enough.

Comment: Or ``IncDay(date, -1)``